# how to customize hoverinfo in plotly histogram?

Tags: r, histogram, plotly

there

I created a histogram from plotly and tried to put CDF on the hoverinfo. Somehow the "CDF"s shown were not right. I think I didn't quote the correct bin info. Here is the code.

```
cdf <- ecdf(iris$Sepal.Length)

plot_ly(iris) %>% 
  add_trace(x=~Sepal.Length, 
            type='histogram', 
            hoverinfo='text+x+y', 
            text=~cdf(Sepal.Length))
```

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you got 8 bins and plotly takes the first 8 `cdf()` values. What values would you have expected as _text_?

Comment: I'm a bit confused: you declare a `cdf` variable at the top, but use the unrelated `cdf(Sepal.Length)` inside `add_trace`.

Comment: I was trying to track cdf at different values of Sepal.Length on the histogram, for example, I expect to see P(Sepal.Length<=6) when moving cursor to the middle of the histogram. However, I can't directly quote the variable name in the hoverinfo text as in scatter plots since the variable Sepal.Length was binned.